# Logout from 2 Spring Web Applications when one of them is Timed-out

Tags: java, spring, session, timeout, invalidation

I need to logout from first web application when the second is timed-out, so my second app has this:

```
@Component
public class SessionTimeoutListener implements ApplicationListener<SessionDestroyedEvent> {

@Inject
private Environment env;

private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SessionTimeoutListener.class);

@Override
public void onApplicationEvent(SessionDestroyedEvent event)
{
    log.warn(event.getId());
    log.warn(event.toString());
    sendLogoutRequest();
}

public void sendLogoutRequest() {
    String portalLogutURL = env.getProperty("portalURL") + "/logoutTatami";
    log.debug(portalLogutURL);
    try{
        CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(portalLogutURL);
        CloseableHttpResponse response1 = httpclient.execute(httpGet);
        try {
            System.out.println(response1.getStatusLine());
            HttpEntity entity1 = response1.getEntity();
            EntityUtils.consume(entity1);
        } finally {
            response1.close();
        }
    }catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}

When second app is timed-out, method works and request is sent.

And the first app has

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/logoutTatami",method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void logout(HttpServletRequest request) {
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();

    log.warn("logging out " + counter++);
    log.warn("logging out session with id " + session.getId());


    session.invalidate();
}
```

When i try to open "url/logoutTatami" in browser it works and session is invalidated, however when my first app sends GET request to "url/logoutTatami" session is not invalidated and I get no errors. My question is how do I invalidate session on some GET request (I've also tried using POST - doesn't work either). Is it even possible? O maybe there's a better solution for my problem?

Comment: Are you using spring-security to authenticate the users?

Comment: @Selva yes I and using it

Comment: Please post your spring-security.xml and web.xml

Comment: @Selva I'll post it tomorrow since I am at home and don't have access to code right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By any chance are you accessing both of your webapps in the same browser window? I think it works in the browser because you already have a session in that browser so Spring Security knows who to logout. Try accessing the logout url in incognito mode.

Since these are 2 different web applications they have different session handlers. Webapp1 doesn't know the sessions in webapp2. Simplest solution is for you to create a way to store the session ID of user that logged-in in webapp1 to webapp2. You can just use a Map to store these sessions. When webapp1 timedout pass the current session ID to webapp2. Search for that session and then invalidate.